# How to "tell" the decorator function that the return type is the same as the wrapped function in Python?

Tags: python, types, pycharm

I have a decorator whose return type is the same as the wrapped function return type. Here is a simple example. The code works as it stands, however, it does not provide type hinting for the output value `res`.  Is there a way to specify that `my_decorator` return the same type as the wrapped function `foo` (e.g. both returning variables of type `Foo`)

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    x: str

def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapped(x):
        print("decorated")
        return func(x)
    return wrapped


@my_decorator
def foo(x: int) -> Foo:
    return Foo(str(x))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = foo(1) # no type hinting for res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `ParamSpec` and `TypeVar` so you can refer back to parameters and return type of your passed function. (Docs: [ParamSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec), [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar))

So `Callable[P, R]` is the argument your decorator takes and is also its return type. If they differ during runtime then your static type checker will catch it. The inside function as well should specify that it takes `P` and outputs `R`. Since `ParamSpec` will catch all positional and keyword arguments you will need to declare your inner function with arguments: `*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs`, so your code will end up looking like this:

```
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    x: str

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

def my_decorator(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    def wrapped(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        print("decorated")
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@my_decorator
def foo(x: int) -> Foo:
    return Foo(str(x))
```

Tested using `mypy`:

```
foo(5) # Success: [...]
```